# Grab livestreaming URL from YouTube

Tags: php, lua, vlc, youtube-livestreaming-api

[This script](http://jslover.secsrv.net/VLC/playlist/youtube.lua) extracts real URLs from YouTube and makes it available to the VLC. I can then copy the link and paste it into FFMPEG, which in turn streams the URL for about 4 to 5 hours. Then (I think) the token expires and I am back to the beginning.

Is there a script which extracts the REAL URL from a YouTube live stream?

I am looking for URLs's like this:

```
https://manifest.googlevideo.com/api/manifest.....
```

Or is it possible to parse the LUA script using PHP and write the result into a txt file?

Thanks to the command I almost got there. I can get the stream URL with the use of livestreamer, but how can I write this response onto a txt file? I added `> test.txt` behind the command, and the link was saved onto a txt file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting Youtube livestream URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25563055/getting-youtube-livestream-url)

Comment: Looks promising. I will check it.

Comment: I created a php script which could do this job. But I don't know if it'll work anymore. But you can create one youself. Just take a look at the source of a youtube webpage and find the urls in the script tags. Then parse the html to get the url. Very simple task.

Comment: I just installed livestreamer. I can get the stream url on the command prompt with this command but how can i write this to a file?

livestream.exe URL 720p --stream-url

this gives the stream url but I want this to be written onto a txt file.